# More in depth photography

Tags: hobbyist

I have been trying to get back to work for several years now. I'm an architect (or was) with children and where I am they don't cater for long hour day care facilities. So here we are me over sharing and still seven years later still without a job. I like photographing things. I own a canon Rebel TSi 550D. It's a superficial hobby. Superficial in the sense that it's genuine just lacks the proper knowledge and understand of the various AV TA ISO combinations.
Can you kindly please point me to good website good techniques, anything that can expand my knowledge with photography.
I need a good place to start.

Comment: Check out Matt Granger's Educating Tina series on You Tube.  I found it very helpful.

Comment: There's an entire tag dedicated to beginners: [tag:beginner] Go through those questions. If you have a specific one that has not been answered yet, go right ahead and ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just some tips for your specific case.

Do not be stuck just by one simple concept. What the AV does and the M does? You will learn that reading the manual in 10 minutes. After reading the manual move the settings and compare the results.

But it is a lot more important to go out and shoot! Take pictures, push yourself in watching the surroundings.

You will not make a business by just having a camera. The bad news is that to make a business you need a lot more than the camera.

Either you have some basic equipment, a cupple of external speedlights and you know how to use them properly (and I do not mean how to move the dials) or you are an exceptional artist that have a sublime eye and sensibility to capture emotional images from everyday life.

So besides reading the manual and reading this forum... **GO OUT AND SHOOT!. Come back, post images with your initial evaluation and recive feedback**.

Do not waste precious time watching tutorials on settings.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you kindly please point me to good website good techniques, anything that can expand my knowledge with photography. I need a good place to start.

This very site (photo.stackexchange.com) is a good place to start. Read all the questions that interest you. Don't limit yourself to just the current ones -- you can sort questions [by votes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) or [popularity](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) and find some of the really good ones. When you find topics that interest you, Google around and read what you can.

For a more structured approach, hit the bookstore or Amazon -- any introductory photography book should have plenty of good information to get you started. For lighting and exposure topics in particular, check out the Lighting 101 series at [strobist.com](http://strobist.com).

Comment: Thanks. Reading beginner tag sounds like a good place to start  didn't know it was there. Thanks again